# Python .map nested DataFrame Dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, nested, recode

I have data nested in a dictionary that I would like to recode with another nested dictionary.

Diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2WKJ.png).

The files dict is the location of the data I would like to recode based on information from the refs dict.

I would like to say if any column header in files is the same as a value in the NAME column in df2, look at the corresponding row of the SOURCE column in df2 and apply the refs information to that column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "Log": ["1114","1115","1116","1117","1118","1119","120"], "Gender": ["2","2","2","-111","1","1","2"], "Race": ["1","2","3","4", "-99", "2", "3"], "Other": ["1", "4", "2", "1", "1", "3","2"] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"NAME": ["Gender", "Race"],"SOURCE": ["MALE_FEMALE_LIST", "RACE_LIST"]})
df3_0 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["0", "1", "2"], "MALE_FEMALE_LIST":["Select", "Male","Female"]})
df3_1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"], "RACE_LIST":["Select", "American Indian","Asian", "Black or African American", "Other"]})

#### Nested Dicts
# df1 are dataframes nested withing a dictionary (files)
files = {}
files['start'] = df1
files['end'] = df1
del(df1)

# df3 are dicts nested within a dictionary (refs)
df3_0 = df3_0.set_index("ID").T.to_dict('list') # Convert df3 to dict
df3_1 = df3_1.set_index("ID").T.to_dict('list') # Convert df3 to dict
refs = {}
refs['MALE_FEMALE_LIST'] = df3_0
refs['RACE_LIST'] = df3_1
del(df3_0, df3_1)
```

If I do as below I get an `Error (KeyError: 'Gender')`

```
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
        files[row["NAME"]] = files[row["NAME"]].map(refs[row["SOURCE"]])
```

This seems to work but there is a Type error:

```
for df_name, df in files.items():
    for _, row in df2.iterrows():
          df[row["NAME"]] = df[row["NAME"]].map(refs[row["SOURCE"]])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the values of the dict df3_01, df3_11 to strings.

`In your code:`

```
# df3 are dicts nested within a dictionary (refs)

df3_01 = df3_0.set_index("ID").T.to_dict('list')
for key, value in df3_01.items():
    df3_01[key]=value[0]
df3_11 = df3_1.set_index("ID").T.to_dict('list') # Convert df3 to dict
for key, value in df3_11.items():
    df3_11[key]=value[0]

print(f'df3_01={df3_01}')
print(f'df3_11={df3_11}')


Output:

df3_01={'0': 'Select', '1': 'Male', '2': 'Female'}
df3_11={'0': 'Select',
'1': 'American Indian',
'2': 'Asian',
'3': 'Black or African American',
'4': 'Other'}enter code here

 print('modified df')
 print(df)

 Output:

 modified df
 
    Log Gender  Race    Other
    0   1114    Female  American Indian 1
    1   1115    Female  Asian   4
    2   1116    Female  Black or African American   2
    3   1117    NaN Other   1
    4   1118    Male    NaN 1
    5   1119    Male    Asian   3
    6   120 Female  Black or African American   2enter code here
```

Comment: Hi @Priya I'm not sure how you got the modified df? which part of the original code is around the "enter code here" parts? Thank you.